# Change the boolean value of 'available' Array (e.g at index 4 which taken from user input to false) using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Please see the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shIZW.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use update like this

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "available.3": false // index 3 means element number 4
  }
})
```

if you are using mongoose your query is like this

```
Model.update({}, // model name instead of Model
{
  $set: {
    "available.3": false // index 3 means element number 4
  }
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/cMWOtIw5L_J